# Is a GraphQL related to Graph Database?

Tags: graphql

According to wikipedia: [Graph Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database)

> In computing, a graph database (GDB) is a database that uses graph structures for semantic queries with nodes, edges, and properties to represent and store data.[1] A key concept of the system is the graph (or edge or relationship). The graph relates the data items in the store to a collection of nodes and edges, the edges representing the relationships between the nodes.

If a database has a GraphQL API, is this database a Graph database?

Both terms sound very similar.

Comment: graphql is like another http transport like grpc or rest.

Answer (score 2):

They are not related. GraphQL is just an API technology that is compared to REST . Think it as another way to implement the Web API and it has nothing to do with where the data is actually stored or the storage technology behind scene. For example, it can be used as a Web API to get the data from [PostgreSQL](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/) too.

But as GraphQL treats the data as an object graph, in term of API implementation, it may be more matched when working with the Graph database. It may be easier to implement as we may delegate some graph loading problem to the Graph database to solve rather than solve it by ourself.